# Polygonize floating-point image

Tags: gdal

I am trying to convert a TIFF file to SHP using GDAL:

```
gdal_polygonize.py GLDAS_NOAH025_M.A201711.021_30_01.tif GLDAS_NOAH025_M.A201711.021_30_01.shp
```

The TIFF file has values from 0.0001 to 0.5 however when I run the gdal_polygonize.py in the terminal with the above simple code all the values are removed. This does not happen with other bands of the same file, so it looks like GDAL is rounding it all down to 0.

I have tried experimenting with changing the TIFF file data format with `gdal_translate -ot Float64` however no luck. Does anybody know a good solution?

[image: TIF]

[image: SHP]

Comment: Polygonization is a kind of reclassification. It only really works with discrete values as found in integer rasters. You need to convert the raster to integer first (best to be 8-bit or less).

Comment: Multiply the raster by 10000 so the range is 1 to 50000, polygonize, divide the polygon attribute by 10000. However, if you end up with too many values to be polygonize you will need to aggregate the values: reduce the multiplier/divisor constant (something like 8000, 6000, 5000, 4500, 4000, 3725 etc..) until the process works. I think the maximum number of values that can be polygonized is 65535 but am not totally sure.